# Webpack 4 bundled JS library code undefined in HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues with (what I believe) my webpack config. I have a main.js file which is compiled by Webpack. The compiled JS code is added to the HTML page with a `script` tag.

However, when I try to call the function in my compiled JS code I get an error. Also when I console log my entire bundled library I get an empty object.

Is there something I'm missing? I've been through almost any 'solution' that I could find on the web but I keep getting an empty object back without my exported functions.

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './_build/assets/js/main.js',
    './_build/assets/scss/main.scss'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/components/project/js/'),
    filename: 'main.js',
    library: 'myLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '../css/app.css'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

My main.js:

```
const myFunction = function(){
  console.log('My Function')
}

module.exports = {
  myFunction
}
```

Compiled Webpack bundle:

```
var myLibrary =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./_build/assets/js/main.js":
/*!**********************************!*\
  !*** ./_build/assets/js/main.js ***!
  \**********************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("var myFunction = function myFunction() {\n  console.log('My Function');\n};\n\nmodule.exports = {\n  myFunction: myFunction\n};\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://myLibrary/./_build/assets/js/main.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./_build/assets/scss/main.scss":
/*!**************************************!*\
  !*** ./_build/assets/scss/main.scss ***!
  \**************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://myLibrary/./_build/assets/scss/main.scss?");

/***/ }),

/***/ 0:
/*!***********************************************************************!*\
  !*** multi ./_build/assets/js/main.js ./_build/assets/scss/main.scss ***!
  \***********************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("__webpack_require__(/*! ./_build/assets/js/main.js */\"./_build/assets/js/main.js\");\nmodule.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_build/assets/scss/main.scss */\"./_build/assets/scss/main.scss\");\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://myLibrary/multi_./_build/assets/js/main.js_./_build/assets/scss/main.scss?");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

My HTML calling myFunction():

```
<script>
console.log(myLibrary)
console.log(myLibrary.myFunction())
</script>
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myLibrary.myFunction is not a function
```